# Is alcheMo available?

Tags: java, iphone, java-me

Is it possible to develop iphone apps with java? I'd prefer to use alchemo over [xmlvm](http://xmlvm.org) because of the superior features that it offers. Can I do that? Is anyone else doing that? I've looked all over their site for the download link, but can't find it! Is it available? If so, where?

http://www.innaworks.com/alchemo-for-iphone-java-me-j2me-to-iphone-porting/

Comment: "How do I find something on website X" is not a programming question.

Comment: @cable729: It's not very polite to call other's "stupid". It certainly won't help you with answers either.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to help find download links. Rather than asking where certain links are, ask a more general question about developing for the iPhone with Java. Let the users here provide you with resources if they feel they're relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to program with Java? Yes.  There are also implementations of C# with Mono that work (kinda) with the iPhone.

Is it ideal?  Probably not.  Objective-C really is the first class citizen on the iPhone and the majority of information, resources and help will be centered here.

As for alchemo?  This looks like one of those times you will actually have to contact New Zealand if you really want more info.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.innaworks.com/Download